# Querying a query

Tags: query-posts, get-posts

Let's say I have a query stored in a array.

I want to parse this array, find the first posts inside this array that match a certain value from a certain key, and so extract the whole post.

Is there a elegant way to do it ? Or, is it possible to run a query_posts() inside this array ?

Thanks !

---

**Edit:**

*Sorry, just learning to use this fantastic website, need to learn correct use.*

The purpose is to make a `get_posts()`, and display the posts not in a row, but at different places in the homepage where there is a place for a Beauty category post, a Mode category Post, etc. As any post could be in several categories, I cannot just ask for the last post in the category: a post could be in two places at the same time.

My idea is to just make a get_posts query, store the result, and parse it so i could take record of what post are displayed and what are not.

So, I make a query with `get_posts()` are store result in a variable. As I don't want certain posts to stay in the query, I use `'post__not_in'`, which is `array` with posts `ID` I don't want.

```
function request_highlights($exclude_ids) { 
/* request that will populate my hightlight feed */
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => 16,
'category'  => null,
'orderby'   => 'post_date',
'order'     => 'DESC',
'post__not_in'  => $exclude_ids,
);

return get_posts( $args );
}

$highlights_posts = request_highlights($slides_id);
```

So at this point, I have a variable which is a objet, I guess, with all needed data.

What I want to do is to get, say, the first post in the objet that has the `cat_ID=5` (for example).

What i'm doing right now is :

```
foreach ($highlights_posts as $highlights_post) {
        $fetched_post = get_the_category($highlights_post->ID);
            foreach ( $fetched_post as $fetch_cat) {
                if ($fetch_cat->cat_ID == $cat_sq) {
                    $sq_post_id = $fetch_cat->cat_ID;
                    break 2;
                }
            }

    }
// stuff to do like get_post($sq_post_id);
```

Now i realise that I would need to remove that post `ID` from my list `$highlights_posts` so I cannot pull it twice. I guess i need to learn more about arrays ?

Comment: A query stored in an array? Code sample please.

Comment: @scribu Sorry, maybe i'm using wrong terms. This should be an objet.

First, the query :

 `/* requete pour peupler highlights */
 $highlights_posts = request_highlights($slides_id);

function request_highlights($exclude_ids) { 
 /* la requete qui va peupler le slider */
 $args = array(
 'numberposts'  => 16,
 'category'  => null,
 'orderby' => 'post_date',
 'order'  => 'DESC',
 'post__not_in' => $exclude_ids,
 );

 return get_posts( $args );
}`

Comment: Don't post the code in a comment. Update the question.

Comment: This question makes no sense can you post code examples and say exactly what each thing is rather than what you refer to it as, e.g. someone said the FAQ page in another question but they actually meant the page showing the faq category

Comment: can you translate the french and put it in your original question so we can see the formatting? Its unreadable as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// store the IDs of the posts we've already displayed to prevent duplicates
$used_ids = array();

$highlights_posts = request_highlights($slides_id);
foreach( $highlights_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    // check if we've already done this post
    if(in_array($post->ID,$used_ids)){
        // skip to the next one
        continue;
    }
    // we haven't done this post before, add it's ID to the list
    $used_ids[] = $post->ID;
    // do stuff e.g. the_title(); etc
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**edit**: Having seen your code would it not make more sense to put the category ID in the function or as a parameter instead of doing `'category' => null` ? It would save you from doing the if statements and the category loop

Comment: Thanks, this enlights me about the use of setup_postdata()

But I would to like to do so only to specific posts, not all of them.

Comment: in that case you need an if statement just after setup_postdata that checks for some condition, such as if post is newer than 2 days do this, or if post is 500 characters long or more do this etc

Comment: Ok, I think that would work. But if I want to not display twice the same post, I need a way to store that i already have pulled it from the object. Is there any way to modify this object without having to send another query?

Comment: reply to your edit : i have to think about it, this could be another good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I will use two parameters, one for the cat_ID, one for the number of posts (in case I need more than one). This would be more clean than my initial approach : I will need to make different request, but i'll add every post_ID displayed to the the array I use for excluding ID, this looks consistent. I still would be curious to know if there is a simple way to manipulate (add, delete, extract for display) the kind of objects returned by get_posts(). Many thanks.

Comment: Its easy, when in your loop, do stuff to the posts that you want, skip the ones you dont want. Can you mark this as accepted or change the question so that its no longer an unanswerable question?

Comment: or be clearer on exactly what it is you want because you're being very vague and open ended

Comment: I want to pull out of the variable the first post with id=5, display it. Then pull out of the same variable the first post with id=6, display it. Then pull out again the first post of any cat which it not the same as the ones already displayed, display it. And doing it a way that I could change rules and cats easily, without ever having the same post twice on the page. Do you think my initial question is still too vague ? Anyway, i'll do some testing tomorrow, and come back to close and amend the question, if it's ok.

Comment: You cannot do this in one query, you will need multiple queries. Separate them out into each step rather than trying to combine them all and then doing tests and if cases, it'll be much easier

Comment: Code is working now, I get to the same conclusion from your remark about 'category=null'. Is it relevant to publish code here as it is the answer of the problem : displaying severals loops on a page without doublons ?

Comment: I don't understand, what is a doublon? It's still not clear what you want, is there an actual specific answer that would satisfy you or is this open ended?

Comment: Is your problem fixed?

Comment: I've changed the answer, as far as I can see from your question and details, this now answers your question. If it does not, please explain why. If you have further things, please open a second question, or I'll have to flag this question. And be specific.

Comment: Doublons is having something in double. You had answer my question since yesterday, thank you. I just wanted to know if it's relevant to publish the full code resulting from this discussion for others, or not.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the accepted answer button ! Clicked now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yay!!!!!!!! ^_^